# Git: Add commits from same branch to master

Tags: git

I have the situation shown in the picture:

[image: gitk screenshot]

How do I move the master head to point to the top commit (Added preferences) because currently I cannot push to the remote repository as it says everything up to date (expected, since master is not pointing to the most recent commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --ff-only <hash of topmost commit>
```

Answer (score 2):

While on the "Added preferences" commit, try `git merge master`. Depending on whether you want fast-worward or not - you may add `--ff` flag.

Comment: I have tried that before and it just says 'Already up-to-date'. This happens whether I fast forward or not